# Java program , array programs

Tags: arrays

The question is write a Java program to store 30 numbers in an atom then store number of digits in another RE display the number in one column and the number of digits in another column after arranging the numbers in descending order of the digits

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure about your question...

If you want to write a simple console program then I would higly recommend something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //creating empty ArrayList;
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    
    //populating arraylist with sample data
    for(int n = 0; n < 30; n++)
        numbers.add(n);

    //Sort numbers descending
    numbers.sort(Collections.reverseOrder());
    
    //Outprint numbers in descending order
    for(Integer i : numbers)
        System.out.println(i);
}
```